# Error of relativistic kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, speed-of-light, approximations

I have recently begun working on the special relativity theory. I have then made the taylor series for the gamma factor to show that we get the classic formula for kinetic energy:

$$E _ { k i n } = m c ^ { 2 } \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { 2 } x ^ { 2 } + \frac { 3 } { 8 } x ^ { 4 } - 1 \right) = m c ^ { 2 } \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { 2 } \frac { v ^ { 2 } } { c ^ { 2 } } + \frac { 3 } { 8 } \frac { v ^ { 4 } } { c ^ { 4 } } - 1 \right) = \frac { 1 } { 2 } m v ^ { 2 } + m c ^ { 2 } \cdot \left( \frac { 3 } { 8 } \frac { v ^ { 4 } } { c ^ { 4 } } \right)$$

> Question: Now I have been trying to figure out how some people claim, that an error at 1% of energy appears at 11% lightspeed.

I can, however, not reach that conclusion. I get 14% instead:

$$\frac { 1 } { 2 } \frac { v ^ { 2 } } { c ^ { 2 } } = \frac { 1 } { 100 } \Rightarrow v ^ { 2 } = \frac { 2 c ^ { 2 } } { 100 } \Rightarrow | v | = \sqrt { \frac { 2 c ^ { 2 } } { 100 } } = 0,14 c$$

Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.  Dividing the relativistic kinetic energy by this yields

\begin{align}
\frac{(\gamma - 1)mc^2}{\frac{1}{2}mv^2} &\approx \frac{\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{3}{8}mv^4/c^2}{\frac{1}{2}mv^2} \\
&= 1 + \frac{3}{4}\frac{v^2}{c^2}
\end{align}

Thus, the relativistic and classical kinetic energies differ by 1% when $\frac{3}{4}\frac{v^2}{c^2} \approx 0.01$, i.e. when $v \approx 0.115c$.

Your error was using the first term of the Taylor series (the $\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}$), which is actually just the classical kinetic energy, rather than the second one, which is the first-order relativistic correction.

Answer (score 3):

You actually want to make the second term have 1% the value of the first:
$$
\frac{3}{8}mc^2 \beta^4 = 0.01 \left ( \frac 1 2 mc^2 \beta^2 \right )
$$
where I'm using $\beta = v/c$. Solving for $\beta$
$$
\beta^2 = \frac{4}{300} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \beta =0.115
$$
which is the 11% you were looking for.